What is the intuition/ intension behind the eigenvalue and eigenvector step in PCA?
One step in the PCA Algorithm is the calculation of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors where the covariance matrix is given. What is the intuition behind the step?

The step you've mentioned in your question plays a crucial role in the PCA algorithm, as it provides the key intuition behind dimensionality reduction. PCA is used to reduce the dimensionality of data while preserving as much variance as possible, and calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix is essential to identify the directions (principal components) that capture the most significant variation in the data. This step helps in transforming the data into a new space with fewer dimensions, while retaining the core structure and patterns.
Covariance Matrix:
The covariance matrix captures the relationships between different features or dimensions in the data. Each element in the matrix represents how much the two features vary together. Diagonal elements represent the variance of individual features, while off-diagonal elements represent the covariance between pairs of features.
Eigenvectors (Principal Components):
The eigenvectors of the covariance matrix represent the directions or axes in the feature space where the data varies the most. These are the "new" axes along which the data can be projected. Each eigenvector corresponds to a principal component, and the direction of the eigenvector defines a new feature direction. These principal components are the key axes of the data’s variance.
Eigenvalues:
The eigenvalues associated with the eigenvectors represent the variance in the data along each principal component. Larger eigenvalues mean that the corresponding eigenvector explains a greater portion of the variance in the dataset. This helps identify the most important directions (or principal components) to retain.
Intuition:
The calculation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors effectively reduces the dimensionality of the data by focusing on the directions (eigenvectors) that capture the most significant variance (eigenvalues). This allows PCA to transform the data into a new coordinate system where the first few principal components capture most of the variability in the data, enabling effective dimensionality reduction and feature extraction.
References
=> https://medium.com/@dareyadewumi650/understanding-the-role-of-eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues-in-pca-dimensionality-reduction-10186dad0c5c
